# Atom Package Tree View?

Tags: atom-editor

I just started using Atom and can't figure out how to display files/folders that are included in .gitignore. I've seen posts that say to uncheck hide vcs ignored files in tree view but I can't even find tree view, haha!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three things you need to check:

1.) There is a option in the "View" menu to toggle the tree view:

[image]

2.) If it's still not visible, please check if the Core Package "tree-view" is enabled:

[image]

3.) Now to get Atom showing you VCS ignored files, you need to disable "Hide VCS Ignored Files" on the Settings pane of the "tree-view" package:

[image]